# jQuery - Create pagination displaying X divs per page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a page that displays news on wordpress, and the plugin that I'm using doesn't allow automatic pagination, so I want to create a system that detects the number of divs with class="Y" and display X divs per page.
I want to do this with jQuery, I know I should have some code to ask a question but all I need is some initial push, or if someone knows a plugin or library to use that would be helpful too.

Comment: use jquery to hide the pagination. calculate the total pages, check if user is scrolled to bottem of page, if he does make ajax call to nex page url extract the blogs from the response and append it to the main content

Comment: I may have explained myself wrong, I want to create the pagination not hide it. because as it is right now all the posts will appear in a single page with an endless scrollbar.

Comment: it will not possible without server side coding, because you are not able to find out total pages. you have to load all the content and then you have to hide it. waste of network bandwidth and slow loading and worst User experience. Use server side pagging for this and modify the plugin

Comment: if you some how find total item count then you can utilize the ajax to make the same request with button click

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll see what i can do... :)